# parse tr in style component using beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have style component in `html` as shown below.

```
<style>
  tr[data-row-company-id="27"] {
    font-weight: 500;
  }

  tr[data-row-company-id="27"] a {
    color: var(--ink-900);
  }
</style>
```

I need to parse `company-id` which is 27 here. I am able to find style component as below

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
item=soup.find('style')
```

I am not sure how do I proceed ahead. Kindly provide solution.

Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to get that info:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<style>
  tr[data-row-company-id="27"] {
    font-weight: 500;
  }

  tr[data-row-company-id="27"] a {
    color: var(--ink-900);
  }
</style>
'''
soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
trs = soup.select('style')
for t in trs:
    desired_info = [x.split('[')[1].split(']')[0] for x in t.text.split('}') if len(x) > 1]
    print(desired_info)
```

Result:

```
['data-row-company-id="27"', 'data-row-company-id="27"']
```

You can drill down further and extract the number only if you want, etc.
BeautifulSoup documentation: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: is there any soup function that will help me extract number without much string manipulation

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware, @BharatSharma. BeautifulSoup will parse the HTML and will give you access to the actual tag content. You need to extract the data you want from that string (`tr` is not an actual element/tag, is just part of the string existent in `style` tag).